# Improve on python public interface data parser

Tags: python

I would love some thoughts on this class that a wrote to extract user information from a logfile line.

I'm concerned about design patterns and the complexity of the code. The extract_user method feels especially awkward.

The class should be used as a public interface ala:

```
parser = UserExtraction(s)
data = parser.extract_user()
```

Now, the majority of the strings that I pass in will simply not be authentication strings. How do I make this available as some sort of response code / error-message to an end user? Right now I'm using self.error_message = yadayada. But I have a feeling this is not very pythonic.

I didn't write any documentation yet since I'm very uncertain about the general design.

Every detail is appreciated, I'm trying to get better at this.

```
import re
import logging
import os
import ConfigParser

class UserExtraction():

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def _string_identification(self):
        identifiers = {
                'Successfully logged in' : 'login', 
                'logout' : 'logout',
                }
        regex_patterns = {

                #TODO Store regexpatterns in outside file
                "login" : "(\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: \[([0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}) ## (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\] (.+?) - Successfully .+? Role: (.+?),",

                "logout" : "(\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: Unable to ping (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}), going to logout user (.+)"

                }
        for key, value in identifiers.iteritems():
            if key in self.string:
                self.event_type = value
                self.regex = regex_patterns[value]
                return True
        return False

    def _matching(self):
        self.matches = re.search(self.regex, self.string)
        if self.matches: 
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def _match_to_dict(self):
        matches = self.matches 
        if self.event_type == 'login':
            self.userinfo = { 
                    'date_time' : matches.group(1),
                    'mac_addr'  : matches.group(2),
                    'ip_addr'   : matches.group(3),
                    'login'     : matches.group(4),
                    'role'      : matches.group(5)
                    } 

        elif self.event_type == 'logout':
            self.userinfo = {
                    'date_time' : matches.group(1),
                    'ip_addr'   : matches.group(2),
                    'login'     : matches.group(3)
                    }
        if self.userinfo:
            return True 

    def extract_user(self):
        if self._string_identification() == True:
            if self._matching() == True:
                if self._match_to_dict() == True:
                    return self.userinfo
                else:
                    self.error_message = "COULD NOT PARSE USERINFO INTO DICTIONARY"
            else:
                self.error_message = "COULD NOT MATCH AUTHENTICATION STRING"
        else:
            self.error_message = "NOT AN AUTHENTICATION STRING"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH + '/settings.cfg')))
    filename = config.get('defaults', 'file_location')

    LOG_FILENAME = config.get('defaults', 'log_location')
    LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s %(message)s' 
    LOG_LEVEL = config.get('defaults', 'logging_level')
    #TODO Change datefmt to be consistent with Apache logfile
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, format=LOG_FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M:%S', level=eval(LOG_LEVEL))

    sample_strings = []

    sample_strings.append('''Jan 2 15:32:49 cam-1/10.0.0.1 Authentication: [01:26:b2:F8:39:27 ## 172.16.197.23] Anonymous - Successfully logged in, Provider: anon, L2 MAC address: 00:26:B2:F2:39:87, Role: User, OS: Mac OS 10.6''')

    for s in sample_strings:
        Processor = UserExtraction(s)
        Processor.extract_user()
        if hasattr(Processor, 'userinfo'):
            print(Processor.userinfo)
        else:
            print(Processor.error_message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserExtraction():
```

Either put `object` as an explicit base class, or don't have the parens.

```
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def _string_identification(self):
        identifiers = {
                'Successfully logged in' : 'login', 
                'logout' : 'logout',
                }
        regex_patterns = {

                #TODO Store regexpatterns in outside file
                "login" : "(\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: \[([0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}) ## (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\] (.+?) - Successfully .+? Role: (.+?),",

                "logout" : "(\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: Unable to ping (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}), going to logout user (.+)"

                }
```

I'd combine these two dictionaries into one list of tuples. I'd also probably make a global constant. Its not clear to me that putting it into an external file would help.

```
        for key, value in identifiers.iteritems():
```

You don't gain much using iteritems here

```
            if key in self.string:
                self.event_type = value
                self.regex = regex_patterns[value]
```

Don't pass data between your method by storing it on the object. That just obscures what is happening. Anything the caller needs to know should be returned not stored.

```
                return True
        return False

    def _matching(self):
        self.matches = re.search(self.regex, self.string)
        if self.matches: 
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Just `return matches` or `return bool(matches)` rather then introducing an if block to convert a bool into a bool.

```
    def _match_to_dict(self):
        matches = self.matches 
        if self.event_type == 'login':
            self.userinfo = { 
                    'date_time' : matches.group(1),
                    'mac_addr'  : matches.group(2),
                    'ip_addr'   : matches.group(3),
                    'login'     : matches.group(4),
                    'role'      : matches.group(5)
                    } 

        elif self.event_type == 'logout':
            self.userinfo = {
                    'date_time' : matches.group(1),
                    'ip_addr'   : matches.group(2),
                    'login'     : matches.group(3)
                    }
```

Python's regular expressions have a named group feature. You can name the groups in the regular expression and thus simplify this code.

```
        if self.userinfo:
            return True 

    def extract_user(self):
        if self._string_identification() == True:
            if self._matching() == True:
                if self._match_to_dict() == True:
```

Don't use `== True`. Just `if self._string_identification():`

```
                    return self.userinfo
                else:
                    self.error_message = "COULD NOT PARSE USERINFO INTO DICTIONARY"
            else:
                self.error_message = "COULD NOT MATCH AUTHENTICATION STRING"
        else:
            self.error_message = "NOT AN AUTHENTICATION STRING"
```

This is python! Throw exceptions, don't store error messages.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

It's usually best to put your main code in a main function that you call from here.

```
    ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH + '/settings.cfg')))
    filename = config.get('defaults', 'file_location')

    LOG_FILENAME = config.get('defaults', 'log_location')
    LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s %(message)s' 
    LOG_LEVEL = config.get('defaults', 'logging_level')
```

Convention says that ALL_CAPS is for constants. These aren't constants

```
    #TODO Change datefmt to be consistent with Apache logfile
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, format=LOG_FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M:%S', level=eval(LOG_LEVEL))

    sample_strings = []

    sample_strings.append('''Jan 2 15:32:49 cam-1/10.0.0.1 Authentication: [01:26:b2:F8:39:27 ## 172.16.197.23] Anonymous - Successfully logged in, Provider: anon, L2 MAC address: 00:26:B2:F2:39:87, Role: User, OS: Mac OS 10.6''')
```

Considering combining these two lines into a string literal.

```
    for s in sample_strings:
```

Avoid single letter variable names, they are hard to follow

```
        Processor = UserExtraction(s)
        Processor.extract_user()
```

By convetion Processor should be the name of a class. Local variables should undercase_with_underscores. Furthermore, should this even be a class? It looks to me more like the job for a function.

```
        if hasattr(Processor, 'userinfo'):
            print(Processor.userinfo)
        else:
            print(Processor.error_message)
```

Here's me reworking of your code:

```
import re
import logging
import os
import ConfigParser

PATTERNS = [
    ('Successfully logged in', "(?P<date_time>\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: \[(?P<mac_addr>[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}:[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}) ## (?P<ip_addr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\] (?P<login>.+?) - Successfully .+? Role: (?P<role>.+?),"),
    ('logout', "(?P<date_time>\w{3}.+?\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+?Authentication: Unable to ping (?P<ip_addr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}), going to logout user (?P<login>.+)")
]


class UserExtractionError(Exception):
    pass

def extract_user(string):
    for key, regex in PATTERNS:
        if key in string:
            match = re.search(regex, string)
            if match is None:
                raise UserExtractionError("Could not match authentication string")
            return match.groupdict()
    else:
        raise UserExtractionError("Not an authenication string")


if __name__ == "__main__":


    sample_strings = [
        '''Jan 2 15:32:49 cam-1/10.0.0.1 Authentication: [01:26:b2:F8:39:27 ## 172.16.197.23] Anonymous - Successfully logged in, Provider: anon, L2 MAC address: 00:26:B2:F2:39:87, Role: User, OS: Mac OS 10.6'''
    ]

    for sample in sample_strings:
        try:
            print extract_user(sample)
        except UserExtractionError as error:
            print error
```

Lightly tested. I didn't keep the logging code.

Comment: Thank you Winston. What a phenomenally detailed answer. I can't come to terms with the fact that somebody would take time out off their day to teach me how to code. Thanks for the effort, your explanations are tremendously helpful.